# How to read data frame using iotools chunkwise?

Tags: r

I am having issues using the `iotools` R package to read data in chunkwise form and update column names. What am I doing wrong?

`Read` works fine when I run the above code without `colnames` statement, then I am able to read the data but column names are `V1, V2, etc`

```
require(iotools)
fc <- file("/temp.csv","rb")
read_table <- function(chunk) {
        # Create a matrix
        m <- dstrsplit(chunk, sep = ",", col_types = rep("character",3), nrows = 100, strict = FALSE)
        colnames(m) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
}
data<- chunk.apply(fc, read_table)
close(fc)
```

```
data
[,1]    [,2]    [,3]
"col1"  "col2"  "col3"
"col1"  "col2"  "col3"
"col1"  "col2"  "col3"
```

Comment: Can you rename the columns after you read everything in?

Comment: @JamesBonkowski, I am able to, however I want to process information in chunks and process the dataframe. If i rename columns after reading the entire data, then entire data is loaded into RAM which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong in your code is that the function is returning whatever colnames()<- returns, which is the column names. If you add a last line with `m` in your `read_table()` function, it would work.

But you don't need a function at all! You can name `col_types` and these names will be used as column names. See below:

```r
library(iotools)
fc <- file("/temp.csv","rb")
mycols <- setNames(rep("character",3), c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
data <- input.file(fc, dstrsplit, sep = ",", col_types = mycols, nrows = 100, strict = FALSE)
close(fc)

data
```